# Having trouble with comparing a char with a string (both arrays) and printing the result?

Tags: c

I'm doing an introduction to programming module as part of my university course, and our most recent project has got me quite stumped. Basically the user needs to enter a sentence and that would get translated to morse code. I'm really stuck at the comparing the text entered by the user to the morse code. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet[27] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\0' };
    char morse[26][5] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };
    char string[256];
    printf("Please enter a sentence to be converted to IMC: \n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    string[strlen(string)] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(string); i++)
    {

            if (strcmp (string, alphabet))
            {
                printf("%s ", *(morse + i));
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: `string[strlen(string)] = '\0';` stores '\0' at the exact place where the '\0' already is. In C strings are terminated with '\0', there is nothing like a length stored somewhere. `strlen()` simply counts how many characters are before a '\0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your line with fgets. Are you sure you want to compare `strcmp(string, alphabet)`? I think you meant something like

````
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet); j++)
    {
            if (string[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                printf("%s ", *(morse + j));
            }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I tried something similar before but hadn't quite figured out the right way to put it all down. Very useful!